# Convert instgram file name (Number) to date

Tags: php, date, extract, filenames

i Download 2 files from instgram

```
504273856298686966_186593000.mp4
1445150401635783037_186593000.jpg
```

This part (_186593000) is dedicated to the user ID from which I downloaded the two files.
What I'm interested in is the part before (Underscore _) that specifies the date of the file

When I used (Bulk Rename Utility) program, it changed the name of the two files (based on the actual date of the two files, not the name) to the following:

```
504273856298686966_186593000.mp4 TO 2013-07-20_18-29-09.mp4
1445150401635783037_186593000.jpg TO  2017-02-07_22-22-54.jpg
```

Is there a way For the extraction the date based on the filename (504273856298686966 AND 1445150401635783037) by php code?

Answer (score 1):

The prefix does not seem to have a format that corresponds to a datetime.

My assumption is that the Bulk Rename Utility used the metadata of the picture to get the date.

You should have a look at the [EXIF extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php) , in particular the `exif_read_data` function, which extracts lot of data including the date.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a result of [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), than like a timestamp, so I think no, there is no way to extract time from it. However, if you will download images through your own script, you can add a timestamp to the filename.